# Is there difference between .jpg and .JPG for android?

Tags: android, jpeg

I wonder if there is any difference between image extensions `.jpg` and `.JPG`. I encountered a problem in that .JPG images cannot be opened with the following code:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String path,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        Log.e("PATH", path);
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        // Calculate inSampleSizeа
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        if(b!=null){
            Log.d("bitmap","decoded sucsessfully");
        }else{

            Log.d("bitmap","decoding failed; options: "+options.toString());
        }
        return b;
    }
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        Log.d("bitmap", "original options: height "+ height + " widnth "+width+" inSampleSize "+inSampleSize);

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
            // guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
            Log.d("bitmap", "options: height "+ height + " widnth "+width+" inSampleSize "+inSampleSize);
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

If I call

```
decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(path, 80, 60)
```

on *.JPG image, the returned bitmap is null. 
I'm asking if they are generally implemented in different way or it is specific for Galaxy S3? (I was not able to repeat it on Galaxy Tab 7.7 or on HTC phones.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android runs on Linux operating system, which is case sensitive.

If the file has the extension in lowercase, like this: ".jpg", so you should refer in the source code. If the file has the extension ".JPG", also, the same should be written in code.

Comment: My path and file extensions are correct. So what you said is hold, but I get bitmap which is null.

Comment: Try to confirm this by creating a `File` object from your path, and then use `file.exists()` method to check. If returns `false`, then the path is incorrect, if `true` but you still get a null bitmap, then... I'm not sure... maybe the file is corrupted and can't be decoded.